# How to programmatically access the iPhone trusted certificate store?

Tags: iphone, security, encryption, ios, certificate

I need to get the certificates from the iOS built-in (X.509) certificate store, and be able to read/parse them in order to decide whether to trust a server or not. Any idea what the APIs are to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

iOS will do all the trust evaluation for you.

The iOS [Certificate, Key, and Trust Services Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices/Reference/reference.html) is a good place to start.

Comment: mindthief, did you find a way to get the trusted certificates out of the system store using Security.framework? I see there is an evaluation function, but I want to get the trusted certs from the system and use them with OpenSSL (also on iOS).

Comment: @MartijnThé, I also need to be able to read the certs and use them with OpenSSL. Did you find a way to do this?